# Arch drives changed and now boot isn't working

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, arch-linux

On my machine, I dual boot windows and linux. It was working fine as of a few weeks ago. Now it doesn't even boot. Originally, my drives were as follows:

```
/dev/sda5 = EFI
/dev/sda6 = swap
/dev/sda7 = root
```

Then somewhere along the line, my windows OS added a drive and moved everything so now it is like this

```
/dev/sda6 = EFI
/dev/sda7 = swap
/dev/sda8 = root
```

Now when I try and use my arch partition, it cannot load because it tries to boot into the original root partition, `/dev/sda7` but it doesn't realize that it was moved to `/dev/sda8`. This is causing it to not work because it cannot recognize the swap filesystem. I can use the arch installation usb and mount the drives and interact with my files, but I want it to work on startup. Is there any way I can specify that I want to point to different drives somewhere for boot? I checked my `fstab` and the drives were there but they were still pointing to the right UUIDs from `blkid`. What can I do to fix this?

Edit: The solution was to modify my `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf` file and point to the right drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root partition is not discovered from fstab<sup>1</sup> – it is specified directly in the kernel's command line using the `root=` parameter. Whatever bootloader you're using for Linux, either edit its configuration file from the live USB, or make temporary changes directly at the boot menu (usually the <kbd>E</kbd> key allows editing an entry), to have the root= parameter point to the correct partition.

You'll probably find that the parameter directly specifies the root partition by its number (sda7). It's best to immediately replace it with an UUID-based path (just like you have in fstab).

---

<sup>1</sup> Might not apply to dracut initramfs.

Comment: This worked! Since I'm on arch so the file was located at `boot/loader/entries/arch.conf`. Thank you so much!